# log4j2 - rolling file not created

Tags: log4j2

I just moved to log4j2. It works totally OK, but rolling file is not created. I've searched around, but haven't found any clues ( there are some similar topics on stackoverflow, but they don't seem to help me ).

Here is my configuration:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration status="warn">
<Appenders>
    <RollingFile name="RollingFile" fileName="logging-file.log" filePattern="logging-file-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}-%i.log">
        <PatternLayout>
            <pattern>%d{ISO8601} %X %5p %c{1}: - %m%n</pattern>
        </PatternLayout>
        <Policies>
            <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="100 MB" />
        </Policies>
        <DefaultRolloverStrategy max="10"/>
    </RollingFile>

    <Console name="Stdout" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
        <PatternLayout pattern="%d{ISO8601} %X %5p %c{1}: - %m%n"/>
    </Console>
</Appenders>

<Loggers>
    <Root level="info">
        <AppenderRef ref="Stdout"/>
        <AppenderRef ref="RollingFile"/>
    </Root>
</Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

Any help would be highly appreciated!
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Your filePattern contains a %d (date conversation pattern) and a %i (index within the specified date pattern, in your case day). However, you only specified a SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy in the rollover Policies section. You also need to add a TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy. That way you will get the desired combination of time based and size based rollover.

For details see https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/appenders.html#RollingFileAppender

Comment: Thanks for the answer. How can I add it? Quick search in google for "DateBasedTriggeringPolicy log4j2" didn't give me any results.

Comment: My bad: it's TimeBased... not DateBased. Apologies. Updated answer.